# Error Loading Fasttext model in GCP Dataflow from GCS Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, bucket, fasttext

I am not able to load the fasttext model in Dataflow. I have the model stored in a bucket and the path is
**gs://fasttext_models/model1.bin**

Below is the way I call:

```
model_1= fasttext.load_model('gs://fasttext_models/model1.bin')
```

I get the below error:
**ValueError: gs://fasttext_models/model1.bin cannot be opened for loading!**

PS:
I used to get the same error when I was loading fasttext locally. But adding Absolute Path fixed this issue.. I am not understanding how to fix this in GCP

Comment: Can fasttext load model directly from GCS? If not, you need to use a more standard library that fasttext understand. You can try gcsfs for example.

Answer (score 1):

Likely `fasttext.load_model(str)` can only load files from the local filesystem.  It doesn't look like it can take an arbitrary open file handle, so your best bet is to copy the data to the local filesystem and then load it from there, e.g.

```
from google.cloud import storage

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
  local_model_file = tmp_file.name
  remote_model_file = storage.Client().bucket('fasttext_models'). blob('model1.bin')
  blob.download_to_filename(local_model_file)
  model_1 = fasttext.load_model(local_model_file)
```

Comment: Yes! This works! We have to download the file and then load it