# How can I deploy a fasttext model on google cloud?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, fasttext

I just want to have a model I can reach via  REST API, and the model just has to be this :

```
import fasttext
ft = fasttext.load_model('pretrained model location')
```

But I want it to be on the Google Cloud platform because the model takes 7GB of RAM. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried or investigated so far?

Comment: I tried to google answers, I tried to create a model on the google cloud platform, but it's not clear whether or not you can just deploy a fasttext models. To deploy a model you need a framework, either scikit, tensorflow or a last one I forget, but fasttext doesn't use those frameworks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stackoverflow.com/questions/68760682](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760682/error-loading-fasttext-model-in-gcp-dataflow-from-gcs-bucket)

Comment: Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?